# How to reverse Fn/F-Key behaviour in Ubuntu on Mac?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, fn-key

I have Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted on my Mac.
In OS X I have System Prefs > Keyboard set to "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as Standard Function keys"

In Ubuntu this is reversed & I need to always use Fn/F-key to achieve the same result.

Is there any way to reverse this behaviour.

Comment: Which do you consider 'inverted'?... & bear in mind that the FKeys will be **only** FKeys in Ubuntu, not 'system function' keys.

Comment: @Tetsujin I want to use F1 to F12 without Fn key in Ubuntu.

Comment: That should be the default - & unchangeable. You mean it isn't & you have to use Fn/Fkey to make them work?

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not know English very well, I want disable FN key.

Comment: I've re-worded the question to be clearer to native English speakers. I don't know Ubuntu well enough to be able to answer, but I hope my re-write will prompt someone who does know to provide an answer. Wish you luck.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same configuration. 
By default, on Ubuntu, the functionality is default.

For you to use function keys as `F1,F2` :

run the below in terminal:

`sudo su -c "echo -n 0x02 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"`

PS: I have used the answer from here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/449001/how-do-i-activate-function-keys-without-pressing-the-fn-button-in-the-mac-keyboa

Comment: This has to be re-applied after each bootup!

Answer (score 2):

A very clearly written answer is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior

I have tested it, and it works like I expected (Pressing F2 now gets me F2, not "increase screen brightness")

I did find that the reboot was not optional - to see the change, I had to reboot.

> 1. Run the following command to append the configuration line to the file /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf creating it if necessary:
>
> $ echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
>
> 2. Trigger copying the configuration into the initramfs bootfile.
>
> $ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
>
> 3. Optionally, reboot
>
> $ sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows PC, there is a BIOS (UEFI) option to make the <kbd>F[x]</kbd> keys behave normally (i.e. require pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> to control volume, brightness etc.). Your Mac might have a similar [Open Firmware](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/enter-bios-command-macbook-31823.html) option. While booting, hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd>,<kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> keys simultaneously. [Quora has some more info on the options.](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-access-BIOS-in-Mac)

Comment: afaik, Intel Macs don't have open firmware, & EFI has no shell like OF used to. Essentially, there's nothing to get into before the OS starts to load